# IllegalStateException when reusing MediaRecorder instance

Tags: android, mediarecorder, android-mediarecorder, android-mediaprojection

Hey I'm trying to make MediaRecorder record the contents of my screen. It works when I'm making a recording for a first time but when I try to record the screen for a second time it fails. Here is relevant code:

```
void startRecording(String directory,String filename,MediaProjection mediaProjection) {
    this.mediaProjection=mediaProjection;
    this.directory=directory;
    this.filename=filename;
    initRecorder();
    prepareRecorder();
    virtualDisplay = createVirtualDisplay();
    mediaRecorder.start();
}

void stopRecording() {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    mediaRecorder.reset();
    if (virtualDisplay != null) {
        virtualDisplay.release();
    }
    if (mediaProjection != null) {
        mediaProjection.stop();
        mediaProjection = null;
    }
    initRecorder();
    prepareRecorder();

}

void setScreen(int screenWidth, int screenHeight, int screenDensity) {
    this.screenWidth = screenWidth;
    this.screenHeight = screenHeight;
    this.screenDensity = screenDensity;
}

void prepareRecorder() {
    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

void initRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(512 * 1000);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(directory + "/" + filename + ".mp4");
    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES).getAbsolutePath()+"/vitalij.mp4");
}
```

So in my activity I create a new instance of this class once then after pressing the button the startRecording method get's invoked. Then user can press stop recording which calls stopRecording method. When app is destroyed i release the mediaRecorder object.
This is the error I get:

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
        at com.example.xxx.myapplication.VideoRecorder.initRecorder(VideoRecorder.java:77)
        at com.example.xxx.myapplication.VideoRecorder.startRecording(VideoRecorder.java:30)
        at com.example.xxx.myapplication.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:134)
```

I'm sure that I have the correct permissions set and the first video gets created fine. The problem only occurs when making the recording for a second time.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're executing these two lines of code:

```
initRecorder();
prepareRecorder();
```

at the end of your `stopRecording()` function and again in your `startRecording()` function.

When you try to call `mediaRecorder.setAudioSource` in `initRecorder()` after the audio source has already been set, you get an `IllegalStateException` because it's in the incorrect state.

If you look at the state diagram on [the Android MediaRecorder reference page](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html), you'll see that a `MediaRecorder` must be in the Initial state to call `setAudioSource()`, but yours is in the Prepared state after `stopRecording()` has been called and you try to call `setAudioSource()` again.